# Error while try to add splash screen to Xamarin forms -Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to create a splash screen to my app.
I am using Xamarin forms, and I currently testing only in Android

However I am receiving this 2 errors

1)Failed to generate resource table for split '' "Failed to generate resource table for split ''".

2. Severity Cod'android:windowBackground' with value '@drawble/splashscreen'.

will appreciate any help to solve this issue

thanks.

here is my styles.xml:

```
<resources>

 <style name="Theme.splash" parent="android:Theme">
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawble/splashscreen</item>
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>    
 </style>

 <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
 </style>
 <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
 <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without 
android:-->
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<!-- Set theme colors from 
http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
<!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
<item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
<!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
<!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
     which is used to tint widgets -->
<item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
<!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
     colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

<item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
 </style>

<style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
<item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

and here is the code I added to Activity:

```
    [Activity(Label = "SplashScreen", MainLauncher=true, NoHistory=true, Theme = "@style/Theme.splash")]
public class SplashScreen : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
    }
}
```

and this is the main acitivity:

```
[Activity(Label = "RegestrationAppComp", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = false, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you create your splashscreen.xml file, you must change its properties. I've followed these steps:

- Right click the splashscreen.xml file and select Properties, a window will show up at the bottom.
- On the field `Build Action`, change the value to `AndroidResource`
- On the field `Custom Tool`, write `MSBuild:UpdateGeneratedFiles` (or copy what's written on other files above in the same folder or from the `values/styles.xml` file.

Answer (score 1):

Please add your image(in your case image file name is "splashscreen") in drawable folder using visual studio. For this, you have to right click on "Drawable" folder -> click on "Add Existing Item" -> select your image from your laptop/PC drive location and click on "Add".. Thats it !!! Now you can build and deploy solution again..